# Ambivalent responses?

Tags: oral, questions

I'm a very ambivalent person, so it's important to me to be able to answer people in a distinctly "sort of, whatever" kind of way. English examples include:

- Sort of
- Kind of
- I guess
- Sure
- Whatever

What are some good, comparable responses in French to yes/no questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few more options, on the positive side:

- *c'est (bien) possible* — (quite) possibly
- *c'est pas impossible* — there's a chance / you certainly have a point
- *certainement* — sure, I'd believe/allow it
- *a priori* — seems so, currently

neutral:

- *en quelque sorte* — sort of
- *plus ou moins* — more or less
- *oui et non* — yes and no
- *oui mais*. (and you are supposed to explain what the condition is at some point)

on the negative side:

- *si on peut dire* — somewhat, but we can't really say so
- *mouais* — mhmm + a very small *ouais*
- *bof* — maybe kind of, but still

Comment: Really good answer.

Answer (score 4):

Tonalité positive

- si on veut
- on peut dire ça
- plutôt oui/non
- je pense
- peut-être
- tu crois ?

À noter que le contexte et les indications non verbales jouent beaucoup et qu'au moins dans le cercle des personnes que je fréquente, ce genre de réponses tient assez souvent de l'euphémisme (donc avec valeur d'un non franc) ou de la litote (avec valeur d'un oui franc).

Tonalité neutre

- Qu'importe ?

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que dans le cas précis des *kinda* / *sorta* ce qui se rapproche le plus en langage plus familier, est l’utilisation des mots *genre* et *style*.

> "Combien de beurre as-tu mis dans ta recette ?" (How much butter in your recipe?)
>   "Je sais pas, genre 100g"  (I don't know, 100g or something I guess)

ou

> "Est-ce un style de musique reggae ?" (Is this some sort of reggae
>   music?)

Comment: On peut également noter le très proche "espèce de", bien que l'expression soit généralement connotée de manière plus négative.

Comment: Note que l'OP mentionne explicitement les questions oui/non.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to informal style, *en gros* + *oui (ouais)/non*, may be what you are looking for, a more formal equivalent would be *à peu près*

> *— C'était bien ton saut à l'élastique depuis l'ISS ?
>
>   — **En gros**, ouais*